# Почему эта функция не вызывает бесконечную рекурсию?

Tags: php

Ведь в конце функции стоит декремент — как `$count` до 10 вырастет то?

```
function test()
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count;
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }
    $count--;
}
```

Пример с php.net

Comment: Так и вырастет, сначала в глубину опустится на 10  позиций в стеке, а потом по очереди всё продекрементирует.... Не понятно, в чём вопрос..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так и вырастет, сначала в глубину опустится на 10 позиций в стеке, а потом по очереди всё продекрементирует.

Предлагаю вооружиться дебаггером и трассировать выполнение кода пошагово на меньшей задаче (До двух, например):

```
function test()
{
    static $count = 0;

1    $count++;
2    echo $count;
3    if ($count < 2) {
4        test();
5    }
6    $count--;
}

$count=0 - test[1](): 1-4
$count=1 -   test[2](): 1-4
$count=2 -     test[3](): 1,2,3
$count=3 -     test[3](): 6
$count=2 -   test[2](): 6
$count=1 - test[1](): 6
$count=0
```

Comment: предлагаю вооружиться карандашом и листком бумаги, дальше - по тексту